# issues with ajax form inside jquery UI popup in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I was experimenting with jQuery UI and MVC3 and I stumbled upon the following issue:

I have very basic page that uses AJAX

```
<%: Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = 1 }, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "dialog", OnSuccess = "DisplayPopup" }, null)%>

<div id="dialog" title="Location">

</div>
```

This is the controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return Content("Saved!");
    }
```

and partial view edit:

```
<b>whatever</b>

<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "Home",
    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "editForm",
        HttpMethod = "POST"
    }))
{%>
<div id="editForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
    <% } %>
```

the code above works fine.

now I add the jquery UI popup code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayPopup() {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    }

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

after that in Firefox and Chrome it works fine, whereas in IE8 I see the following issue:

1. click edit - makes AJAX call to Edit(int id) action and shows the edit view inside a popup
2. click save - makes AJAX call to Edit() and shows the text "Saved!"
3. close the popup
4. click edit - AJAX call to Edit(int id) - again
5. click save - **this time it makes FULL postback** (only in IE)

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I just did the same with thickbox (http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) instead of jQuery UI popup and it worked fine in all three browsers...

Comment: looks like there might be an issue with jqueryUI modal dialog - I submitted a bug ticket here http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6679

Comment: Try destroying the dialog on the close event and creating the dialog new every time in the displaypopup function

Answer (score 0):

Try this seeing it works the first time but not the second. Create the dialog new every time and destroy it when you are done.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DisplayPopup() {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 600,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }, close: function() {
                $(this).dialog("destroy");

            }
    });
    }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble: worked in FF, but not in IE8.

Try adding something to the partial view response.

I was having this same trouble in IE and ended up adding `@ViewBag.Message` to the partial view response, where `ViewBag.Message = "Submitted " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();` was assigned in the controller on Post.

This suddenly and surprisingly caused the partial view to render in the correct target  element instead of loading the view as a new page in IE8.